# how can i store value of jquery variable into php variable in the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here is my JavaScript code :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('.project').change(function()
        {
            var pro=$(this).val();
            if(pro=='none')
            {
                $('.hd').hide();
                alert('Please Select a project');
            } 
            else
            {
                $('.hd').show();
                $.post("test.php",{pid:pro},function(result){
                    $('.result').append(result);
                });    
            }
        });     
    });

</script>
```

And here is my HTML and PHP code :

```
<select id="pro" name="pro_id"  class="login project" style="width:83.6%; height:30%; ">
    <option value="none">Select a Project</option>
    <?php 
        while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($pro9)){
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rs['project_id']; ?>">
        <?php 
            echo $rs['pro_name']; 
        ?>
        </option>
    <?php 
        } 
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do exaclty . please add some description

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you cannot do that.
PHP is a server side language and is executed in server machine.
But Javascript is a client side language and is executed on user's browser,
So first of all, PHP is interpreted on the server and after result is sent to the user, javascript can run.
So at this step, you have no way to do such thing